# Book about a supervillain who can pulls guns out of hammerspace - Cover shows him with two huge guns

Tags: story-identification, books, super-hero

I remember pulling this up on Amazon as a Kindle book a few years back (probably about 2013-2014) where it was being shown as a recommendation due to the books I was reading (possibly *Soon I Will Be Invincible: A Novel*). The cover showed the supervillain, I think in a purple outfit, brandishing a huge gun in each hand. The bit of the story that I read (a preview) had him doing an interview and explaining his ability to pull guns out of nowhere. I'm pretty sure that his name was themed off of that ability, but I don't recall it exactly.

Anyhow, any chance that someone else recognizes this book?

Comment: Has the same feel as *Reckoners*, but no such character is in that series, and I can't find it either.... will keep trying.

Comment: @Radhil: I know the guy you're talking about, got ridiculed in the book for that being his only power (and being a pretty lousy shot at that). But no, this was its own book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly ["Supervillainous!: Confessions of a Costumed Evildoer"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13627754-supervillainous) by Mike Leon, which came out in 2011.

The cover does indeed show a guy in purple with what looks like multiple guns though it could easily be mistaken or misremembered as a single large gun):

[image]

Although the official description is generic "learn the secrets of supervillainy" and doesn't describe the character's powers or anything, [a review](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1353581134?book_show_action=true) on Goodreads suggest the points you remember:

> Baron Hammerspace, the main character of Supervillainous﻿, gets his opportunity to really shine as a supervillain

We see the character's name is indeed related to his ability.

And from:

> This book is written from the perspective of a fictionalized version of the author. He's taken on a journalistic position to see what life is like as a supervillain. And the villain he chooses to follow, well, he might have just figured out how to bypass the whole "good always wins" thing.

We get a style of book that makes it likely to contain the interview preview that you remember reading.